# How do i fix a typeError when using node.js to connect to Mongo db and is my code correct?

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database called Exams and inside Exams is a document called Math_Exams so I am trying to store that in an array but my connection to the database does not work and this error appears after typing node app.js (name of the file) into the terminal:

```
/Users/giulianafalconio/Desktop/Nueva carpeta/app.js:14
connectToDb().then(() => {
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/giulianafalconio/Desktop/Nueva carpeta/app.js:14:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
this is the code I have:
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')

const {connectToDb, getDb} = require('./examsdb')

const app = express()
let db

connectToDb(
    (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            app.listen(3000, () => {
                console.log('app listeing in port 3000')
            })
            db = getDb()
        }
    }
)

app.get('/Exams', (req, res) => {
    let Math_Exams = []
    db.collection('Math_Exams')
        .find()
        .toArray(Math_Exams => Math_Exams.push(Math_Exams))
        .then(() => {
            res.status(200).json(Math_Exams)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // catches errors
            console.error(error)
            res.status(500).json({error: 'Could not fetch the documents'}) // meaning server error
        })
})
```

examsdb.js:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')

let dbConnection

module.exports = {
    connectToDb: (cb) => {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Exams')
            .then((client) => {
                dbConnection = client.db()
                return cb()
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                return cb()
            })
    },
    getDb: () => dbConnection,
}
```

So the database information
[MongoDB local database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnMlL.png)

is supposed to display in tab like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pqHj.png)

but safari browsers says they can't connect to local host:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0TUP.png)